# How do you counter Camouflage first?

Tags: natural-selection-2

As marines, how do you counter the aliens rushing camouflage?  A handful of camo Skulks can walk into the main (or any location that the marines are trying to build) and kill everyone before they hardly have a chance to react.  Observatories are costly, weak, and immobile, and scan is on a not-insignificant cooldown.

Staying in a tight ball helps, but it seems to be impossible to build obs in critical areas (tech points, doubles, etc) quickly enough to not give up control of over half the map and it's resource nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Camo is pretty overpowered, I think it will be changed in future updates.

For now the best viable option is to have your comm get armor upgrades ASAP.

Armor 1 give you an extra 1-2 bites before death which gets you closer to an even fight.

Additionally:

1. Good placement of observatories is essential. They must be placed in locations that give you as much sight out of your bases as possible yet are still protected.
2. Shooting off rounds where they should be.  Try to out think the khara players. I have often guessed where skulks will be and end up killing them before they even move since they think they are safe in their camo.  Yes this does waste ammo but dying is worse.  Like CS or any of these style games players often hide in the same spots.
3. Organize your team. In NS2 a well organized marine team should beat Khara most of the time(although it is rare). If your marines travel in groups with a few meteres inbetween you a skulk taking its first bite should be an easy target since it will still be moving slow out of cloak.
4. Lastly, if your party is about to assualt infested area's the scan really is worth the 3 res.

Currently the Khara win rate is too high so expect certain game mechanics to change.